# Rounddown function gives error "argument not optional'

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting this error called "argument not optional" for the line

```
 If Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(units) = 0 Then
```

at the **"RoundDown**" part. I know the code is pretty messy so bear with me, I'm still new to VBA. There are a lot of posts on this, but I still can't seem to correct this error.

```
Private Sub Command_button1()

Dim buysignal As Range
Dim OHLC As Range
Dim ffdhigh As Range
Dim sellsignal As Range
Dim ffdlow As Range
Dim entryprice As Range
Dim stoploss As Range
Dim exitprice As Range
Dim unitsize As Range
Dim position As Range
Dim n As Range
Dim cll As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim v As Long
Dim units As Long
Dim sl As Long
Dim accv As Long
Dim contsize As Long
Dim risk As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ts As Double


i = 1
v = 0
units = 0
ts = Range("e3")
sl = Range("o1")
risk = Range("l2")
accv = Range("l1")
contsize = Range("e1")
lastrow = Range("a63").End(xlDown).Rows.Count


For i = 63 To 180

        Set OHLC = Range("B" & i & ":" & "E" & i)
        Set ffdhigh = Range("I" & i)
        Set buysignal = Range("M" & i)
        Set cll = Range("B63")
        Set sellsignal = Range("N" & i)
        Set ffdlow = Range("J" & i)
        Set entryprice = Range("p" & i)
        Set stoploss = Range("r" & i)
        Set n = Range("h" & i)
        Set unitsize = Range("t" & i)
        units = (risk * accv) / (contsize * n)


    For Each cll In OHLC


                If cll.Value > (ffdhigh.Value + ts) Then
                '(ignore this) And WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("T" & 63, "T" & 63 + v)) = 0
                buysignal.Value = "buy"

                ElseIf cll.Value < (ffdlow.Value + ts) Then
                sellsignal.Value = "sell"

                Else: sellsignal.Value = ""
                buysignal = ""

                End If


    Exit For
    Next


        If buysignal = "buy" Then
        entryprice = ffdlow.Value
        stoploss = ffdhigh.Value - (n * sl)
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(units) = 0 Then
            unitsize = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(units)
            Else: unitsize = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(units)
            End If

        ElseIf sellsignal = "sell" Then

        entryprice = ffdhigh.Value
        stoploss = ffdlow.Value + (n * sl)



        Else: entryprice = ""

        End If


Next i

End Sub
```

I don't exactly understand what the optional means, any comments would be much appreciated. Thanks so much guys.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try... giving the number of decimals you need?

```
unitsize = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(units, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a second argument that specifies the "number of digits". If you set that to 0 you recover rounding to a whole number:

`If Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(units, 0) = 0 Then`

You need to do the same for `RoundUp`.

Comment: thanks @Bathsheba that worked! i completely missed that grr. I've edited that but now i get the error "overflow" for the line = "units = (risk * accv) / (contsize * n)". tried to search the error here but can't find the solution, what gives? thanks in advance

Comment: contsize * n is most likely zero in that case.

Comment: alright i see that.. is there any way i can go around that? I've tried shifting the positions when setting n but that doesn't work. n is supposed to be the value in Range("h" & i) for i = 63 to 180